# methods of scaling mysql inserts

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-cluster

I've got a php-cli script which makes +2 million mysql queries(1/2 select statements using indexes, 1/2 row inserts of a couple varchar(25), int(5) columns ) on an amazon server's crontab. The script itself takes hours to run. I'd like to get it down to ~5 minutes.

I'm wondering how I might scale up the row inserts to cut the time?(The script is essentially a foreach loop over some api data, so I'm also looking into ways of forking the script per iteration ((as a separate issue))

I've been looking at mysql cluster but know nothing about data warehousing, etc. Does anyone know if this would even be the right place to start looking? Would something like Hive/Hadoop be more appropriate?

--edit
I'm on an ec2 micro-instance for context. I expect that migration to heavier duty instances will be required, but am wondering if there's any mysql-like alternative to plain old mysql daemon that might help

Comment: Increase the CPU, RAM and Get an SSD perhaps? :)

Comment: Scaling inserts isn't easy, and you didn't provide sufficient information. Inserts depend heavily on the IOPS your hard drive can provide (input output operations per second). If you can wrap several tens of inserts in a transaction (and if  you use transactional engine like InnoDB or TokuDB) you might shove a few tens (or hundreds) of inserts in a single IO of your hard drive. Without seeing your code - it's difficult to advise you further. Having an SSD would definitely help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see a huge jump in performance by just upgrading from a micro instance. Micro instances use a burstable CPU profile, you will be running at very low performance for much of that import.

There are a number of things you can do to optimize inserts. Committing as much as you can in a single transaction (InnoDB tables) or disabling index updates (MyISAM tables) can "group" work together in a more efficient manor.

At some point with updating large volumes of data, you will hit the limits of I/O. With EC2 you may want to test RAID configurations or provisioned I/O to see how you can best improve performance.